# Prevent Windows from sleeping / hibernating whilst R script is executed from cmd

Tags: r, windows, cmd

When I execute a long-running R script from the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe), I want my computer to understand that it is "active" and thus remain awake until the script is complete (unless, of course, I manually put the computer into sleep mode).
This is the behaviour observed when I run the script from within RStudio, rather than the command prompt – but RStudio is unsuitable in this case.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436158) points to the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) function in C – is there an equivalent in R or cmd that lets the computer know that it is in use?

Comment: Is it not possible to deactivate automatic sleep mode in windows?

Comment: Deactivating automatic sleep mode will mean that the machine will not go to sleep once the job is complete.

Comment: I usually just manually go into Settings (Windows + I) and then search for *power and sleep*, write down the current settings, then change them all to Never and then when finished change them back.  There are command line programs that you could launch using `shell(...)` from R: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/dont-sleep-prevent-windows-from-standby-shutdown-hibernate-and-restart/ .  Another one is https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/NoDoz .  Also there is the `powercfg` cmd line program that comes with Windows . Some of these may require you be in Admin mode.  Haven't used any of these myself.